# how to formally find decision boundary of linear separable problem with threshold

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hi!

How do I find threshold $\theta=3/2$ here?

Should I do sum over inequalities:

P1: $\theta > 0$

P2, P3: $w_1 * \xi_1^3 + w_2*\xi_2^3 - \theta < 0 $

P4 : $w_1 * \xi_1^4 + w_2*\xi_2^4 - \theta \geq 0 $

then:

$\theta > 1$

$\theta \leq 2$

summing to get mean:

$\theta + \theta = 2 + 1$

so

$\theta = 3/2$

Is it correct?

And boundary line will be: $[-w_2, w_1] + \theta$ ?

## EDIT

Simply guest that its 3/2 its not enough on exam. Besides only solution what comes to my mind is to decide on $W$ vector, then draw orthogonal to it line passing by points (0,1) and (1,0). Vector W will cross line in point D(0.5,0.5). Then we move this line to line' passing by point C in the middle between D and (1,1). Point C should be in (0.75,0.75) so that distance from each side will be maximized (distance to point (0.5,0.5) and (1,1) are the same). Equation of line is $\xi_1 + \xi_2 = 1$ then equation of line' will be $\xi_1 + \xi_2 = 3/2$. If there is better solution I would be happy to see it :D

Comment: Is this your first question here? Make sure to not use images, but rather text, for your questions

Comment: text below image, so whats the problem?

Comment: The text in the image is not below the image

Comment: @yourstruly:  your comment is not nice.  Please refrain from harassing new users.

Comment: ohh, actually i forgot to feed my cats too